# Get current local time using openweathermap

Tags: php, date, openweathermap

I'm using openweathermap api to get weather from different location.
from this I receive :

```
"sys":{"type":2,"id":2008110,"country":"CH","sunrise":1633585192,"sunset":1633626144},"timezone":7200
```

But i don't know How to get localtime using php...

Comment: this might help: [current.dt Current time, Unix](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API provides a UTC time stamp and a time zone offset.

```
$sunrise = 1633585192;
$timezoneOffset = 7200;  //Seconds
```

If a DateTime object is created from a time stamp, the time zone is always UTC.

```
$dt = date_create("@".$sunrise);
```

To get the local time, the object has to be transformed into the correct time zone.

```
$hhmm = sprintf("%+03d:%02d",(int)($timezoneOffset/3600),$timezoneOffset%3600); //+02:00
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($hhmm));
//"2021-10-07 07:39:52.000000"
```

Now the object has the desired local time and the correct time zone.

Comment: Being picky, it's Unix time and UTC is not involved at all because it represents the seconds elapsed since a fixed moment in time, so it's exactly the same value in all time zones. If the API returns a time zone it must be just an informative field, like the country, but it comes in handy to calculate the local time of the events, as you illustrate.

Comment: Right. And the fixed time is January 1, 1970, 00:00 UTC.